# why the console.log prints multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, rxjs6, ngrx-store

Hi I am newbie in Rxjs and its operators.

I am having difficulty to understand below code

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id');

        console.log('Entered in Can-Activate');
        return this.store.select(policy)
            .pipe(
                tap(policy => {
                    console.log('-------------------' + JSON.stringify(policy));
                    if (policy.model.id !== id && policy.meta.loading !== 'progress') {
                        console.log('--------------dispaching-----');
                        this.store.dispatch(new Load(id));
                    }
                }),
                filter(policy => (
                    policy.model.id === id &&
                    (policy.meta.loading === 'done' || policy.meta.loading === 'failed')
                )),
                map(s => s.meta.loading ==='done'),
                take(1)
            );
    }
```

The console output for this is

```
Entered in Can-Activate
-------------------{"meta":{"loading":"start".........}
-------------------{"meta":{"loading":"progress".........}
-------------------{"meta":{"loading":"done".........}
```

Can anyone explain me why below line executed multiple time when function only called once?
console.log('-------------------' + JSON.stringify(policy));

Is it because ngrx store or RxJS operators?

Comment: What does this line do `this.store.select(policy)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.store.select` is an observable.
Every time it the state changes it will emit a new value and the logic inside `tap` will be executed, until the subscription is unsubscribed to.

In your case when the following condition is met,

```
 policy.model.id === id &&
                    (policy.meta.loading === 'done' || policy.meta.loading === 'failed')
```